# How to extract select statement into table field as XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, oracle

I am trying to replicate piece of sql code that's working on a Oracle db to work also in SQL Server. Basically, I need to select certain columns (defined) from multiple tables into one table - its like a union only with variable number of tables. The exact names of the tables aren't defined so in Oracle, I am using user_tables like '%ABC%' to get list of all tables and dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype to execute the created select statement.

In Oracle, I have the following code that's working ...

```
select table_name,                  
   dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select id,name from '|| table_name).extract('/*') rec
from user_tables
where table_name like '%ABC%';
```

I know I could create a variable and execute it into table but I need this to be a SELECT statement in the same way as the oracle piece. Is something like that possible in SQL Server?

UPDATE: I would like the 'executed' result of the generic SQL statement => the output has two columns, table_name as the first columns and the second column (REC) contains the XML block of the select result for each table.

[Desired Output Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BujBM.png)

Comment: Sample XML and expected results would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of tables by selecting from `sys.objects` dynamic management view, where `type` column equals `U` (i.e. user table):

```
select name as TableName, 'select id, objectname, description from ' + name as SelectStatement
from sys.objects o
where o.type = 'U'
  and o.name like '%ABC%'
```

Comment: Hi - that only gives me the generated select statement text - I need the result of the select statement as XML block per row/table.

Comment: You must execute this using `sp_executesql` or `exec`. To get the data as XML, you need to add [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) clause to the select statement.

Comment: So there is no option like in Oracle to have it all in a select statement?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the content of your tables as XML, you need to generate dynamic SQL and execute this statement. Use information from [sys.objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) system catalog view (as @AndreyNikolov suggested)  and retrieve each table content with [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) clause.

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE 
    @stm nvarchar(max),
    @err int

-- Statement generation
SET @stm = N''
SELECT @stm = @stm +
        N' UNION ALL ' +
        N'SELECT ' +
        N'''' +
        [name] + 
        N''' AS [Table], ' +
        N'(SELECT [id], [name] FROM '+
        + [name] +
        N' FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT(''ROWSET'')) AS [Rec]'
FROM sys.objects
WHERE 
    ([type] = 'U') AND
    ([name] LIKE '%ABC%')
SET @stm = STUFF(@stm, 1, 10, N'')

-- Execution
PRINT @stm
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
IF @err = 0 
    PRINT 'OK'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'Error'
```

Comment: Thanks for that - but that's creating a dynamic sql and execute it. I am looking for a solution that does it directly in a select statement - in the same way as the oracle piece.